# using next js and Images and svgs not showing after deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using next js and when i run the code locally everything is working fine but when i deploy it on Netlify using Git images and svgs are not showing anymore, am using background-image : url () property

here is the url https://todo-app-mo.netlify.app/

```
 background-dark {
    background-position: center;
    height: 110%;
    background-image: url("../bg-desktop-dark.jpg");
    transition: var(--transition);
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      background-image: url("../bg-mobile-dark.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, it seems your images are not there or you are pointing into wrong direction. Please look at this link https://todo-app-mo.netlify.app/_next/static/media/bg-desktop-light.3508d620efd5a52bb4ced1338e9bda33.jpg is this correct path?

Comment: yes it is the same path that is working on the local host, actually sometimes it work and other times it tells me that the path is not found, really do not know what is going on there

Comment: Can you try put somewhere else on the server and give it full url? like https://todo-app-mo.netlify.app/images/bg-desktop-dark.jpg

Comment: Thank you all i solved it it was not the path, there was something wrong with my mobile google chrome and when i tried it on Safari and other browsers and other chrome mobiles it worked fine

Comment: Good to hear ^_^